# How to change directory to the cloned repo in Jenkins?

Tags: git, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my Jenkins file:

```
    stage('Clone the Prometheus dashboard repo')
    {
        deleteDir()
        checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/master"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "${Git}", url: "https://testorg/testrepo/test-kubernetes.git"]]])
    }
    stage("Install the dashboards")
    {
    sh '''#!/usr/bin/env bash
        set -x
        cd ${WORKSPACE}
        pwd
        ls
        cd test-kubernetes/kubernetes/Prometheus/kube-prometheus/utils
        cat build.sh
    '''
    }
```

Unfortunately, It is not able to change to the directory. Also in `ls` I do not see the cloned repo.

May I know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the output you see in the above pipeline? usually, you can use `dir("test-kubernetes"){ sh "cat build.sh"}` if the checkout is successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
node {
    deleteDir()
    dir('dir-name') {
        stage('checkout') {
            git branch: 'main',url: 'https://github.com/samitkumarpatel/test0.git'
        }
        stage('do stuff') {
            sh """
                ls -al
            """
        }
    }
}
```

This means when Jenkins start build it will create a folder `dir-name` if not exist on Jenkins job $WORKSPACE and checkout the repo inside that directory.

**test0.git folder structure**

```
├── Jenkinsfile
├── Jenkinsfile.Declarative-n-scripted
├── Jenkinsfile.iffilechange
├── Jenkinsfile.test0
├── README-one.md
├── README.md
├── shared-library
│   ├── src
│   └── vars
│       ├── log.groovy
│       ├── myPipeline.groovy
│       └── oneToTen.groovy
├── src01
│   └── 01.txt
├── src02
│   └── 02.txt
└── src03
    └── 03.txt
```

**Jenkins log output**

[image]

Note- On my example in the output you can't see `test0` folder on the job WORKSPACE because the SCM git plugins checkout subfolder and file, not the root folder.
So on your case you can navigate to the folder like  `cd $WORKSPACE/kubernetes/Prometheus/kube-prometheus/utils`